# Why does my HTTP request (bubble wrap) fail to execute in a Grand Central Dispatch queue?

Tags: http, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, rubymotion

I am doing this inside my RubyMotion application:

```
Dispatch::Queue.concurrent('google').async {
  BubbleWrap::HTTP.get("http://google.com") do |response|
    p response.body.to_str
  end
}
```

This call does not complete.

However if I take the BubbleWrap code outside of the Dispatch queue, it completes fine.

Comment: Change concurrent to new...does that help? `Dispatch::Queue.new('google').async {`

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261122/how-to-run-async-operations-within-a-grand-central-dispatch-operation -- since `HTTP.get` is already asynchronous, can you run it outside of your async block?

Comment: @DylanMarkow: yea running it outside works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BubbleWrap::HTTP` is an abstraction over `NSURLConnection`, which depends on a [RunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) for its asynchronous processing. Unfortunately RunLoops aren't set up on GCD queues, and I haven’t figured out how to start a runloop on a GCD queue. When I've needed the above, I've resorted to instantiating a new `NSThread`, and started the run loop manually instead:

```
action = lambda do
  runLoop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop

  BW::HTTP.get("http://www.google.com") do |response|
    NSLog("Fetched Google!")
  end

  runLoop.run
end

thread = NSThread.alloc.initWithTarget action, selector:"call", object:nil
thread.start
```

This answer is a rehash of [my blogpost on the same topic](http://www.subsis.dk/14/how-to-use-bubblewraphttp-in-a-background-thread) and [Cocoa In The Shell](http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/)